# Bluez map-client --lsmsg=LS_MSG is not listing the messages even there are messages in phone

Tags: linux, bluez

I am trying to list out the messages in my phone's inbox using **map-client**.

I am running the command as:

```
./map-client -d "BD-address of mobile phone" -c telecom/msg/inbox --lsmsg=LS_MSG.
```

It is returning empty Dictionary `{}`.
The other commands change directory, list directory are working fine.

I tried with PTS map server also but same result. How to get the list of messages ?